# 80s sci-fi story about a human negotiating a deal with an organic alien spaceship

Tags: story-identification

The story was set mostly in space. The lead human character was negotiating with an alien spaceship that was organic. It had a hive organism structure with different creatures inside performing the functions of a ship and crew, it was rather like a bee hive or ants nest. The controlling mind of the organic ship instructed one of its worker organisms to leave the ship to interact with the human on his ship in order to negotiate a trade.

The worker was  very nervous and unsure as he had never had to operate autonomously without being told exactly what to do by the main organic ship. He learned a lot in interacting with the human, he appreciated Latino music rhythms and slowly began to understand that the human was trying to trick his ship into a bad deal.

When he returned much changed to his ship the hive mind did not trust him and disposed of him into a recycling pit where he died and was absorbed. He was right; without his guidance the ship was cheated by the human.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this a short story or a novel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is almost definitely Walter Jon William's [*Angel Station*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2427) (1990).

The alien spaceship is called only "Beloved."  The mostly-autonomous unit that negotiates with Ubu and Maria is "General Volitional Twelve."

The negotiations are mostly mutually beneficial, though Ubu does initially sell somewhat antiquated processors as the latest tech.  Beloved uses "music" as part of her internal signalling and control, and Ubu spends time listening to it.  Twelve, in turn, listens to human music, and is particularly concerned with poetic ballads (because they speak to human emotions almost subliminally) and at one point decides that "ladino" music is almost evil.

Twelve is dissolved by Beloved near the end of the story after Twelve had arranged things to favour Ubu and Maria over other human ships that were competing for their business.

> Twelve had not entirely understood his decision to aid Beautiful Maria and Ubu, had only felt an obscure rightness in the act. Likewise he had instinctively opposed Beloved’s scheme to deal with Clan de Suarez and cut off Runaway’s trade. **Beloved had assumed these attitudes to be the result of human contamination**, and she was right. Twelve, her servant, had been polluted by human contact.
>
> What Beloved failed to realize was that she required servants who had been so polluted. **She needed servants who could instinctively recognize human schemes**, who could warn her away from actions that might worsen her situation. Her own icy rationality was not flexible enough to deal with the human threat.
>
> She needed Twelve. She had thrown him away. Now she was more vulnerable than ever.
>
> Twelve shuddered as a new wave of enzymes began assaulting his frame, burning deeper into his flesh, reaching new nerve endings with their chemical claws. Beloved! he thought. I can still save you! And then his thoughts were swept away by a blazing wave of hot, retching agony.

Comment: That's it, many thanks. I'd been wondering about that for years. I'll read it again soon.